# Is array[:, 0:-1] = array[:][0:-1]?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I am following an [LSTM tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/).

In order to divide my training data into input (x) and output (y), I have to do the following command :

```py
X, y = train[:, 0: -1], train[:, -1]
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and generates the following error while printing `train[:, 0: -1]`:

```
> TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), slice(0, -1, None))' is an invalid key
```

I have tried to replace this command by:

```py
X, y = train[:][0: -1], train[:][-1]
```

But I'm quite sure it will not give the same output since it's illogical (in my case), to have sevral inputs & one output.

Here is a minimal reproductible code with a sample of data:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import datetime
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
import numpy

O = [0.701733664614, 0.699495411782, 0.572129320819, 0.613315597684, 0.58079660603, 0.596638918579, 0.48453382119]
Ab = [datetime(2018, 12, 11, 14, 0), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 10, 0), datetime(2018, 12, 21, 14, 0), datetime(2019, 1, 1, 10, 0), datetime(2019, 1, 1, 14, 0), datetime(2019, 1, 11, 10, 0), datetime(2019, 1, 11, 14, 0)]

data = DataFrame(numpy.column_stack([O, Ab]),
                 columns=['ndvi', 'datetime'])

def fit_lstm(train, batch_size, nb_epoch, neurons):
    X, y = train[:, 0: -1], train[:, -1]
    X = X.values.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    for i in range(nb_epoch):
        model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
        model.reset_states()
    return model

train, test = data.values[0:-2], data.values[-2:]

print (train[:, 0:-1])
```

All I want, is to resolve this problem to fit the LSTM model:

```
lstm_model = fit_lstm(train, 1, 3000, 4)
```

Maybe, I have to usse the `shift()` in this case, to pass the last time step as input and the current one as output?
Like this:

```py
shift_steps = 1
train_targets = train.shift(-shift_steps)
X, y = train, train_targets
```

Comment: If it's an invalid key, that would mean your data is a dataframe, not a numpy (2D) array.

Comment: If you really want/need a numpy array, pass `fit_lstm` your dataframe instance `.values` attribute: that's the numpy array : `fit_lstm(train.values, 1, 3000, 4)`. But, better yet, try and use actual dataframe indexing with column names (or use e.g. `.iloc`): `X, y = train['ndvi'], train['datetime']` (guessing here which columns).

Comment: Note that the tutorial somewhere shows this code: `X = series.values;
train, test = X[0:-12], X[-12:]`.

Comment: I've put data.values to set the training, and the command still doesn't work.

Comment: @00, maybe I have to reshape the data for the training set. This is the error I have when I work with ```data.values```and print ```train[:, 0:-1]``` : >print (train[:, 0: -1])

IndexError: too many indices for array

Answer (score 1):

You are using DataFrame, and the slicing is differente.

Assuming the column 'nvdi' holds the features, and the column datetime the expected results of each training data, you will need to refer to them as:

```
X = train['nvdi']
y = train['datetime']
```

I only see two columns in the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
Actually, the datetime column doesn't contain expected results, but the "scale".
my data in NDVI depending on time.
Maybe I have to use pandas.Series instead of DataFrame?

Comment: maybe with my data, I have just to use ```train = data.values[0:-2]```  as the input X. It seems more logical. 
The problem will be then the output y.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found my mistake:
The syntaxe was incompatible with my set of data.

As I mentionned in the last edit of my question, I used the `shift` . It's worked this way:

```py
def fit_lstm(train, batch_size, nb_epoch, neurons):
    X, y = train, train_targets
    X = X.values.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    for i in range(nb_epoch):
        model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
        model.reset_states()
    return model

train, test = data.values[0:-2], data.values[-2:]
shift_steps = 1
train_targets = data.shift(-shift_steps).values[0:-2]
```

||

||

/

```
print (train)
[0.70173366 0.69949541 0.57212932 0.6133156  0.58079661]
```

```
print (train_targets)
[0.69949541 0.57212932 0.6133156  0.58079661 0.59663892]
```

Thank you so much @00 and @Sebas for your help :)